# What does this error mean in SAS: Duplicate column names have been detected

Tags: database, sas

I am new to sas and trying to debug someone else's code. the goal is to merge 3 datasets.

this is the final step in the code I'm trying to run:

```
proc sql; 
    create table foot_all as
        select*
    from foot_paper_merged          
    outer union corr
        select*,discharge_rtw_reason length=84
    from foot_dados_paper_merge         
    outer union corr
        select*
    from foot_dados_ca_dc;              
quit
```

However, I am getting this error message:

Duplicate column names have been detected in the above query which requested that
       CORRESPONDING column names be matched. This situation is ambiguous.

First of all I don't really understand the error message because it is saying that there are duplicate column names...but of course there are duplicate column names! I am trying to merge 3 datasets that may or may not have the same column headings into one!

I don't think I understand what the error message is telling me.

Someone please help me!

Comment: Can you use proc append instead for appending the data? It's generally more efficient if you're dealing with SAS data sets. I may be missing something in the query though.

Answer (score 0):

This error triggers because SAS is already pulling `discharge_rtw_reason` from the `foot_dados_paper_merge` table (via `select *`), and is then instructed to create the variable again (with the length update).  It is not permitted to have two variables with the same name in a SAS dataset. Try changing the length before performing the SQL query.

Alternatively, re-write as follows (presuming `temp_var` does not exist already):

```
proc sql; 
    create table foot_all as
        select*
    from foot_paper_merged          
    outer union corr
        select*,temp_var as discharge_rtw_reason length=84
    from foot_dados_paper_merge (rename=(discharge_rtw_reason=temp_var))        
    outer union corr
        select*
    from foot_dados_ca_dc;              
quit;
```

To clarify - this is an issue regardless of the union operation.  Try running the following (should give a `WARNING: Variable discharge_rtw_reason already exists on WORK.test`):

```
proc sql;
create table test as 
select*,discharge_rtw_reason length=84
    from foot_dados_paper_merge;
```